# Can i control JNI native method invocation name in Java?

Tags: java, native, jnienv, jniwrapper

I stuck with a problem. I use Chilkat for Java and as i understand there is no, any Maven Repo for it. As it is a two-component library - i need to inject .dll, via System.load(). This part is clear to me, but also they provides something, like wrapper, which calls methods in .dll.

So, i don't want to import their .jar to my project, but, then i call native methods by my own it fails with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError. Because, then java tries to invoke a native method it adds some stuff at the beginning of it's name. For example: if i declare native method in my package, then it will be invoked, java will add all package hierarchy names to it's name.

Can i somehow call directly the native method by it's name, without any runtime "adaptations" ?

Comment: "This part is clear to me" and `UnsatisfiedLinkError` are two quite contradicting statements. You've bought some commercial library and it probably doesn't matter what you want ...when already failing to load the DLL.

Comment: Because i understand, that if method in .dll called Java_com_chilcat_updateSomething.
But if i will declare a native method in my package it's name in runtime will be Java_mypackage_UpdateSomething. Correspondingly, JNI will not found this pointer. I can invoke their methods, only from their object hierarchy. But i want to integrate native calls, directly in my application

Comment: As stated, this is some commercial library and they are supposed to provide the support for their product ...which may use encryption and/or obfuscation on either Java or native assembly side.

Comment: It's all about how jni works. There is a class with all native declarations. Even if i wipe all other classes in a library (I can do this, because it's not a Maven dependency.) it will work, and i succeed calling their methods, just because it placed in right package, and then jni makes call, it's adds right method name, composed with package name.

Comment: The question was, can i take control on that jni do automatically ?

Comment: The point is that updateSomething in your package is unrelated to updateSomething in any other package.  It's why the language has packages.  It is a good thing that when X in my package calls Y in package Z, Y in package Z is what it gets, not some other random Y.

Comment: On the other hand, nothing stops you typing 'package anything.you.like' into your source-code editor.  Though you'll have to deal with any resulting conflicts.

Comment: Yep. I know all of that. And if i will create same package hierarchy it will work. But it's a code smell

Comment: So is recreating what they've already provided you.

Comment: The answer is 'yes', by calling 'RegisterNatives()' yourself instead of letting Java do it all. I'm not a lawyer but I sense a licence violation here.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is what you are looking for, but I guess this is closes to what you have described: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo052

Answer (score 0):

[`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html) can generate the bindings you might be looking for ...[DLL export viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) (among several others) can list exported methods. Or for SO, just use `dumpbin /EXPORTS ./filename`. That method names would change at runtime is not a reality, this only happens once when obfuscating them, at build time - which usually excludes all the objects, which need to stay accessible (for reflection).

Just start a new JNI project and learn how it works with vastly reduced complexity. There still is a chance, that this one JAR might pass licensing information in the native assembly - or that the native assembly performs cryptographic functionality for the JAR. An a commercial library is not to be treated alike open source - I'd read THEIR licensing terms, to begin with.